# Variable indefinida en Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel

tengo un error en el que me dice que mi variable posts no esta definida, cuando en realidad si esta. Mi codigo es el siguiente.
El Controlador

```
private $userPhotosFolder = "photos";

public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::orderBy('id','DESC')->where('user_id', Auth::id())->paginate(10);
    return view('profile.gallery', compact('posts'));
}

public function store(ActualizarPost $request)
{
    $file = $request->file('image');
    $filename = str_random(10) . '.' .$file->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $file->move($this->userPhotosFolder, $filename);// subimos al servidor

    $post = new Post;
    $post->user_id = $request->get('user_id');
    $post->description = $request->get('description');
    $post->image = $filename;
    $post->save();

    return view('profile.gallery');
}
```

y mi gallery

```
@foreach( $posts as $post)
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a href="{{ $post->image }}" class="fancybox" rel="ligthbox">
                    <img id="image" src="{{ $post->image }}" class="zoom img-fluid "  alt="">
                    <div class='text-center'>
                        <small class='text-muted'>{{ $post->description }}</small>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        @endforeach
```

Como ven la variable posts esta definida en el controlador, pero aun asi me da el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ese error te muestra despues de ejecutar la funcion store?

Comment: si, guarda en la db, al momento de imprimir da el error

Comment: Ahi esta el problema, en la funcion store al momento de retornar no agregas la variable posts, solo pones la vista ese debe ser el error

Comment: eso estoy haciendo en la funcion index :/

Comment: @PriscilaDuarte ¿Por qué aquí pones `profile.gallery` y en el error marca una vista llamada de diferente manera?, ¿no tendría que ser `profile.form-gallery`?

Comment: es porque estoy usando include dentro de gallery

Comment: @PriscilaDuarte Ya veo cual es el problema, lo pondré en la respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que se puede ver en tu url y en el log de error, te está dando la excepción al hacer post, es decir en el método `store` cuando guardas la entidad `post`.

Una petición `post` no debería de devolver una vista, si puede pero no es para nada una buena práctica, al acabar tu proceso del método `store`, si lo que quieres es devolver la vista de la lista de los `posts`, lo que tendrías que hacer es quitar el `return view()` del método `store` y más bien redireccionar a la ruta de tu método `index()`:

```
public function store(ActualizarPost $request)
{
    $file = $request->file('image');
    $filename = str_random(10) . '.' .$file->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $file->move($this->userPhotosFolder, $filename);// subimos al servidor

    $post = new Post;
    $post->user_id = $request->get('user_id');
    $post->description = $request->get('description');
    $post->image = $filename;
    $post->save();

    //La siguiente línea ya no va: 
    //return view('profile.gallery');

    return redirect()->route('ruta-que-usa-el-metodo-index')->with('msg', 'Se guardaron los cambios');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si esto pasa luego de que haces uso de la función store el error es claro, esta función al finalizar llama la vista 'profile.gallery', pero en ningún momento pasas la variable $posts, lo cual si haces en el index, mi solución es que en donde estas retornando a la vista pongas lo siguiente.

```
    return redirect()->route('ruta_que_llama_al_index');
```

ó

```
    return redirect()->action('App\Http\Controllers\nombre_controlador@index');
```